# Azure File Copy Task failed in VSTS build

Tags: azure, storage, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to copy some files from my one virtual machine where build agent is running to another virtual machine in same virtual network using Azure File Copy Task added in VSTS build step but its failing with error message "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'storgeKey' because it is an empty string".Can anyone help Please

Error

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'storageKey' because it is an empty string.
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: AzureFileCopy
******************************************************************************
System.Exception: Task AzureFileCopy failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1660)

Refer to the workaround mentioned by antmeehan